# MongoDB : applyOps: not authorized on admin database

Tags: mongodb

If I want to restore the oplog from the admin library, can I do it with the following user permissions

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "interalUseOnlyOplogRestore",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { anyResource: true }, actions: [ "anyAction" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

I use the above user and get an error

```
skipping applying the config.system.sessions namespace in applyOps
2024-01-31T14:21:12.145+0000    Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: (Unauthorized) command applyOps requires authentication
```

Comment: According [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/resource-document/#anyresource) you should not use `anyResource`. The same applies to `anyAction`. What do you mean by "restore the oplog" and how did you do this?